# How to create socket connection for chatting in android

Tags: android

I have to develop a chatting application and I want to use socket connection. is there a way in android for it. Which will be better way for long time application.
Give me suggestion about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `Sockets` class? You can use sockets to write and read data between two clients in background threads that update the UI thread with the data received/sent.

Generally with sockets one device (the client) connects to another (the server) and it is expected that the server's hostname will not change. However, you can't guarantee this with devices on mobile networks so a better approach might be to have two devices connect to a well known server that relays chat messages through. If you're just trying to do a basic chat application between devices on the same LAN it would be fine to directly connect them however.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html